# How can I set a Class Public Property as Type List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I want to define a public property in a User Control with a type of List that I can pass a List to and then have the control bind it to a repeater.

```
public partial class RepeaterPager : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public List<T> DataSource;
}
```

The from calling code

```
List<someClass> list = new List<someClass>;
RepeaterPager1.DataSource = list ;
```

I thought this would be simple, but I am getting Error The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) on the line that declares the public property. What am I doing wrong

Cheers

Stewart

Comment: You need to either assign a generic to the whole class, or change the to List<SomeCommonlyInheritedType>.

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible if the class containing property is generic. In theory, you could use generic method:

```
void SetDataSource<T>(List<T> dataSource)
```

but you'll lose type information elsewhere.

Maybe,

```
IEnumerable DataSource
```

will be a better option?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have generic parameters in fields of a class with out the class being generic.

See this answer for info on making a usercontrol generic: [C# generics usercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329362/c-generics-usercontrol)

Or you could just use a non-generic version, such as `IEnumerable` or `IList`.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to define generic Type, or make RepeaterPager generic

```
public partial class RepeaterPager<T> : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public List<T> DataSource;
}
```

Comment: The problem when I do this is that I lose reference to the Page controls in the user control. Presumbaly because the Page is inherits RepeaterPager and not RepeaterPager<T>, so I can no lobger refernece controls such as txtSomeTextField.Text etc..

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for this type of data binding is to define DataSource as type object.  Then, in the set method you can do a runtime check to verify the object is of a type you expect -- throw an exception or debug assert otherwise.

Besides, [Repeater.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.datasource.aspx) is type object anyways ...

Many times I can get away without holding a reference to the datasource, so I pass it directly to the control:

```
public object DataSource
{
    get { return myRepeater.DataSource; }
    set {
        if (value is IEnumerable) // or whatever your requirement is, if needed
            myRepeater.DataSource = value;
        else
            throw new NotSupportedException("DataSource must be an IEnumerable type");
    }
}
```

However, if you really do need to know about the type T, I would consider the following:

1. If possible, use the generic class idea others have suggested.
2. If you need to repeat this pattern for different classes, build a base class or Interface for all your data sources to derive from
3. Use DataSource as type object, but just grab the type at run time using `obj.GetType()`.  (Depending on your needs this may or may not work)