# store Expression<Func<T, bool>> where as a class property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a class that extends the System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView control.
I want to have a property that can save my EF expression to use throughout the control.

Problem is, T is not defined.

```
public sealed class NCGridView : GridView
{
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> _where;

    public void LoadWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        _where = where;
    }
}
```

RedHat suggestion attempt

```
    private Expression<Func<BaseModel, bool>> _where;

    public void LoadWhere<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where) where T : BaseModel
    {
       // Cannot cast from: Expression<Func<T, bool>> to:  Expression<Func<BaseModel, bool>>
        _where = where;
    }
```

Comment: Well... What is T meant to represent? Would storing is as a non-generic Expression suffice? (casting it when needed and known)

Comment: T is the type of the row bound to your GridView. Can you know this at design time? I've never heard of a generic control. No, wait, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329362/c-sharp-generics-usercontrol).

Comment: Can you show an example of how you intend to use the expression?

Comment: @Marc ha I sneaked in my edit before the deadline

Comment: @dtb My overall goal is to have an extended GridView control that will work with my POCO entities. So I can tell the gridview which entity set I'm working with and it will know how to work with them internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 2:
Update:

```
public Expression<Func<BaseModel, bool>> LoadWhere<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where) where T : BaseModel
{
    where = LambdaExpression.Lambda<Func<BaseModel, bool>>(where.Body,where.Parameters);
}
```

Answer 1:
Use:

```
Expression<Func<object, bool>>
```

Supported any type.

Sample:

```
Expression<Func<object, bool>> exp = p => ((Table1)p).Code == 1;
var a = new MyContext().Table1.Where(exp).ToList();
```

Comment: I tested it, some example will be added.

Comment: @RedHat, I think using a generic type vs using a base class was my issue in this case.

Comment: Yes, you right, but so @Marc Gravell mentioned in question comment "IDE hates them(generic)"

Comment: So what's best practice to extend a gridview to abstract default behavior for all of my models that derive from BaseModel?